# Ansible package module keeps installing packages

Tags: debian, ansible

We hava a mixture of CentOS, RedHat, Debian and Ubuntu servers all over the place.  I am trying to install generic packages that have the same name for all Distros.   The package module seems to work only on CentOS / Redhat boxes, but on Debian boxes it keeps on installing the package.  After the script completes the packages are not installed.  Rerun the script and same thing.  I am running Ansible on the latest Mac OS and the version is 2.9.11

What am I missing to get this to work on Debian systems?

I know that as a workaround I can use when: ansible_distribution and determine what version I am running, but that means I have to make the script longer and type the packages twice.

```
## Installs Generic OS independent packages ##
- name: "Installs base packages"
  package:
    name:  "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - tcpdump 
    - wget 
    - screen
```

Comment: This works fine on Debian systems. What is the real problem you are having? Check your apt logs.

Comment: That solved my issue.  The package does get installed, but later on my playbook I install a different package that causes a conflict and removes the original package.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

the question is in fact irrelevant since the code works as expected - author commented:

That solved my issue. The package does get installed, but later on my playbook I install a different package that causes a conflict and removes the original package. Thanks, – user2236794 Oct 25 at 1:44